# How do I deal with directories that have spaces in their names from `find`?

Tags: bash, find, filenames, whitespace

I have this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for file in `find . -type d`
do
  echo $file
done
```

If I have just one directory called `My Directory`, the output is

```
My
Directory
```

How do I fix this?

The `echo $file` is just temporary. There will be other code in there operating on the directories.

Comment: Or the [SO variant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7039579/3076724)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like the following works ...

```
find . -type d | while read dir; do echo $dir; done
.
./my dir
```

Depending on what you're doing, you might be better using `find`'s `-print0` option and `xargs -0`.

The code you've got takes the unquoted output from `find` and uses it as a list of words (split on whitespace) for `for` to iterate over.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use `for` loop, use `while` instead:

```
find . -type d -print0 | while read -d '' -r dir; do echo "$dir"; done
```

Option `print0` prints NULL character at the end of file/directory name (instead of newline) and `read -d ''` interprets it properly.

Comment: This assumes that you use GNU find of BSD find.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use "$file" in your example.

Comment: This doesn't actually work. The `for` breaks it up before it gets there.

Comment: What do you mean breaks it up? Using `echo "$file"` works for me.

Comment: Echo "$file" works on one variable. But in this loop, the for $file has already broken the output of the find command in to a list of strings that were split by spaces. So it's too late already by the time it gets to the echo command.

Answer (score 1):

If you're really just looking to `echo` the results of `find`, you can use the parameter `-print` (or just no additional parameter at all) to have `find` print a list of its results.

If you want to delete the results, there's `-delete` (which can be combined with `-print` to get a list of the deleted files).

If you want to do something else with/to the results, you can use the parameter `-exec` to pass the results as parameters to another command, e.g.

- `find . -type d -exec tar cf {}.tar {} \;` to compress all directories into individual tarballs (one tar per directory, since `\;` makes `find` run the `-exec` command with one result at a time)
- `find . -type d -exec tar cf all-directories.tar {} +` to compress all directories into a single tarball (`+` makes `find` run the `-exec` command with as many results as possible at a time)

Comment: I'll be doing an xattr to remove resource forks on OSX with this. Question edited, thanks.

Comment: Maybe it would be a good idea to issue a __warning__ about `-delete`! Like `deltree` on DOS prompt in Windows, this seemingly inconspicuous option can cause huge file trees to get purged in no time!! So use `-delete` with extreme caution.

Answer (score 1):

Before answering your answer, I highly recommend you reading two question:

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/38906)
- [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/38906)

For your question, you don't need a `for` loop, just find itself:

```
find -type d
```

If you want to do more things, just use `-exec` option (or `-execdir` if your `find` support):

```
find -type d -exec ... +
```

Comment: Just to make one thing clear: for the OP's question, the `for` loop is indeed unnecessary BUT ... it is not necessarily redundant, especially not for `bash` beginners. For example, if you use two loop variables `i` and `j` (with `j` being an altered `i`) or simply a couple different statements, the `for` loop approach (though frowned upon) is easier to comprehend than teaching them the pro solution of `-exec sh -c ... ` which is as if you attempted to teach calculus to a person that only ever learned about basic arithmetics.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set IFS variable in bash:

```
SAVEIFS=IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
...
YOURCODE
....
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

But  what does above code do? , it discard any space and meta char..